# Z-transform of $\sin{(n\frac{\pi}{2}(-1)^{n})}$

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, z-transform

I was trying to do this z transform:

> $\sin{(n\frac{\pi}{2}(-1)^{n})}$

but I don't have the solution. I have divided in 4 cases:
for n=0 0
for n=1 -1
 for n=2 0
for n=3 1

so **4k, 4k+1, 4k+2 and 4k+3**

But now I don't know how to proceed and I don't know if my result is right.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My usual note.  Where certain engineers say "Z-transform", mathematicians say "Laurent series".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already observed that this signal $x[n]$ is periodic: $x[n+4]=x[n]$ for all integers $n$. Therefore we get
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{Z}\{x[n]\} =\sum_{k=0}^\infty x[k]x^k z^{-k} &= 0 + (-1)z^{-1} + 0 z^{-2} + 1 z^{-3} + \sum_{k=4}^\infty x[k]z^{-k} \\
&= -z^{-1}+z^{-3} +  z^{-4} \sum_{k=0} x[k]z^{-k}.
\end{align*}
$$
The last term is equal to $z^{-4}\mathcal{Z}\{x[n]\}$, so from this equation you can distill the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform.

Comment: My result for that z transform is $\frac{-z^{3}+z}{z^{4}-1}$ is this result correct ?

Comment: That looks very correct to me.